# How do I make Average Mark Calculator in PyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to use PyQT to calculate average marks from 1 to 5 (5, 4, 4 = 4,33). It shows me error and why I can't do this. What's the problem?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(412, 239)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 10, 211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setItalic(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.one = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.one.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.one.setFont(font)
        self.one.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);")
        self.one.setObjectName("one")
        self.two = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.two.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 150, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        self.two.setFont(font)
        self.two.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);")
        self.two.setObjectName("two")
        self.three = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.three.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 150, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        self.three.setFont(font)
        self.three.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);")
        self.three.setObjectName("three")
        self.four = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.four.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 150, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        self.four.setFont(font)
        self.four.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);")
        self.four.setObjectName("four")
        self.five = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.five.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 150, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.five.setFont(font)
        self.five.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);")
        self.five.setObjectName("five")
        self.Marks = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.Marks.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 391, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat Medium")
        font.setPointSize(17)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.Marks.setFont(font)
        self.Marks.setText("")
        self.Marks.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Marks.setObjectName("Marks")
        self.Result = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.Result.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 100, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat Medium")
        font.setPointSize(21)
        self.Result.setFont(font)
        self.Result.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.Result.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.Result.setText("")
        self.Result.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Result.setObjectName("Result")
        self.Apply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.Apply.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 200, 75, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.Apply.setFont(font)
        self.Apply.setObjectName("Apply")
        self.Clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.Clear.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 200, 75, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.Clear.setFont(font)
        self.Clear.setObjectName("Clear")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

        self.add_functions()

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Средний балл"))
        self.one.setText(_translate("Dialog", "1"))
        self.two.setText(_translate("Dialog", "2"))
        self.three.setText(_translate("Dialog", "3"))
        self.four.setText(_translate("Dialog", "4"))
        self.five.setText(_translate("Dialog", "5"))
        self.Apply.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Принять"))
        self.Clear.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Очистить"))

    def add_functions(self):
        self.one.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.one.text()))
        self.two.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.two.text()))
        self.three.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.three.text()))
        self.four.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.four.text()))
        self.five.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.five.text()))
        self.Apply.clicked.connect(self.results)
    
    def write_number(self, number):
        marks = []
        marks.append(number)
        self.Marks.setText(self.Marks.text() + number)

    def results(self, number, marks):
        res = sum(marks) / len(marks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I used tkinter before, so I don't know how to make it, because it shows me error:

```
"TypeError: Ui_Dialog.write_number() missing 1 required positional argument: 'marks'"
```

Answer (score 0):

First You have to pass arguments to results function

and `marks = []` will reset the `marks` list every time a button is pressed..
so better make `marks` global variable by `self.marks = []` and append integers to it..

so to append numbers to it use `self.marks.append(int(number))`

and remove the `numbers` argument from results as it is not necessary
so results function will look like this..

```
def results(self, marks):
    res = sum(marks) / len(marks)
    print(res) #or return as your wish
```

`write_number` function should look like this

```
def write_number(self, number):
    self.marks.append(int(number))
    self.Marks.setText(self.Marks.text() + number)
```

and declare the `self.marks` variable after `self.add_functions()` statement

```
self.add_functions()
self.marks = []
```

and change `Apply` button connect Function
`self.Apply.clicked.connect(lambda: self.results(self.marks))`

so `add_function` should look like this..

```
    def add_functions(self):

        self.one.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.one.text()))
        self.two.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.two.text()))
        self.three.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.three.text()))
        self.four.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.four.text()))
        self.five.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.five.text()))

        self.Apply.clicked.connect(lambda: self.results(self.marks))
```

Comment: It's not working :(

Comment: Since `marks` is not dynamic and does not depend on the call context, there's actually no need for a lambda: just directly connect to `self.results` and use the current `self.marks` in there.